# Битовый сдвиг массива байт на ассемблере

Tags: ассемблер

```
.386
.model flat, C

.code
BgZeroShl proc
    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp

    mov edi, [ebp + 8]  ;адрес массива
    mov ebx, [ebp + 12] ;количество элементов
    mov eax, 0 ;счетчик cnt

    mov dl, [edi+ebx-1]
    and dl, 10000000b
    cmp dl, 0
    je exit
    // тут должен быть цикл сдвига
    // правильно ли обращаться к разряду len*8-1 как [edi+ebx-1]
    // не могу понять как реализовать этот цикл сдвига, типо while


    exit:
    mov eax, 0



BgZeroShl endp
end
```

Задача в том, надо совершить линейный сдвиг влево(в сторону старших разрядов) до тех пор, пока в len*8-1 разряде не будет 1. Количество сдвигов записуем в cnt. Если в начальном значении числа М1 разряд len*8-1 == 1 , то сдвиг не выполняем, в cnt записываем 0.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70008/discussion-on-question-by--------).

Answer (score 2):

```
    mov  esi, [ebp + 8]   ; адрес массива
    mov  ecx, [ebp + 12]  ; количество элементов
    lea  edi, [esi+ecx-1] ; edi указатель на последний байт массива
    mov  ebx, edi
    std             ; готовим поиск задом наперед
    xor  eax, eax   ; будем сравнивать с нулем
    repe scasb      ; ищем первый не 0
    je   exit1      ; Вся строка заполнена нулями - выходим
    inc  edi
    sub  ebx, edi   ; ebx расстояние сдвига в байтах

    xor  eax, eax
    mov  al, [edi]  ; eax самый старший не нулевой байт
    bsr  ax, ax     ; получаем номер старшего, единичного бита (в eax)
    mov  ecx, 7
    sub  ecx, eax   ; вычисляем величину сдвига (ecx)

    mov  ah, [edi]  ; готовим старший значащий байт
    dec  edi        ; Внимание: могут быть проблемы, если длина массива равна 1
shift:
    mov  al, [edi]  ; младший байт грузим в AL, что бы его старшие биты вдвинулись в AH
    shl  ax, cl
    mov  [edi+ebx+1], ah ; сохраняем в старший байт
    shr  al, cl
    mov  ah, al     ; готовим старшие биты для следующего цикла
    dec  edi
    cmp  edi, esi
    jae  shift

    inc  edi
    shl  al, cl
    mov  [edi+ebx], al ; запись последнего значащего байта
    test ebx, ebx
    jz   exit1         ; мы в начале массива, обнулять ничего не надо
    xor  eax, eax
    push ebx
firstZero:            ; заполнение 0 оставшихся байт в начале массива
    dec  ebx
    mov  [edi+ebx], al
    test ebx, ebx
    jnz  firstZero
    pop  ebx
exit1:
    lea  ebx, [ecx+ebx*8]; EBX=кол-во-байт*8 + (кол-во бит сдвига 1 байта)
```

Comment: попробовал реализовать битовый сдвиг массива байт, через команду rcl , но в итоге программа компилируется , но не выводит массив. https://pastebin.com/HJXLRF79

Comment: @МишаШостак инструкция rcl циклически сдвигает содержимое регистра. в вашем случае она сдвигает содержимое esi. в esi у вас находится адрес массива arr. Адрес, это такое специальное число, скажем номер ячейки памяти, где начинается ваш массив. И вы это число просто в регистре преобразуете много раз. оно так и остается в регистре, в памяти при этом ничего не происходит. и кстати rcl сдвигает циклически, если сдвинуть на 3 бита число 11110000 получится 10000111, это в любом случае совершенно не то, что требуется

Comment: Данный нюанс, через команду rcl , был указан самим преподавателем, как обязательная команда к выполнению. Он забраковал ваш вариант.

Comment: @МишаШостак ну используйте rcl, в принципе ничего особо страшного в том, что вы сдвините с помощью него нет, только ту часть регистра в которую происходит выдвижение старших бит использовать будет уже нельзя потому что там будет грязь, зато в старшей части после сдвига будет корректное значение. т.е. если вы двигаете ax, то в ah все нормально, а al использовать нельзя. P.S. кстати, `rcl esi, cl` сдвигает содержимое esi на количество бит, находящееся в cl, но в вашей функции cl нигде ничем не заполняется

Comment: У меня возникла проблема, программа выводит пустой массив после сдвигов.

Comment: поместил mov cl, 1 до цикла loop

Comment: @МишаШостак Да, rcl двигает через перенос, значит надо двигать по одному биту, как вы делали изначально. я бы предложил выдвигать один бит и тут же, вторым rcl вдвигать его в другой регистр. И да, разумеется ваш текущий код выведет пустой массив, или не измененный, потому что, как я сказал вам в первом своем комментарии вы вообще ничего не изменяете в памяти. Поэтому странно ожидать, что в памяти что то изменится, если вы в ней ничего не меняете

Comment: Изменил структуру программы, возникает ошибка на push[edi]. https://pastebin.com/FNbh9bVc

Comment: @МишаШостак Логично. Что по вашему делает команда push ?

Comment: Команда push - размещения значения в стек.

Comment: @МишаШостак Совершенно верно. А зачем вы помещаете значение по адресу [edi] в стек, если вы его из стека более нигде не достаете ? (Не считая строки pop ebp в самом конце, которая поместила бы в регистр ebp последнее значение которое было помещено в стек в цикле. А потом еще произошел бы ret по адресу который был занесен туда предпоследним push [edi]) Правда до этих команд дело не доходит, потому что цикл у вас бесконечный и происходит переполнение стека

Comment: Понял, почему цикл бесконечный , оно же переходит на метку end если в определенном разряде будет 1.

Comment: @МишаШостак Не вижу, что бы вы хоть где то проверяли какой то разряд. Вижу только что вы проверяете eax целиком на абсолютное значение 1. и если оно вдруг окажется равно, то вы конечно же из цикла вышли бы. Но в eax у вас в этот момент находится вообще адрес последнего байта в массиве и он гарантированно не равен 1

Comment: Я предварительно в eax занес адрес [edi+ebx-1] разряда , разве на протяжении цикла значение eax не будет меняться? В зависимости от того, что в [edi+ebx-1] разряде

Comment: @МишаШостак Во первых у разрядов нет адресов, вы заносите в eax адрес целого байта, который состоит из 8 разрядов. И адрес этот может быть каким угодно, например пока я отлаживал свой вариант адреса обычно были вида 0x60883, при этом регистр eax может хранить числа до 4 миллиардов, так что даже если бы вы его увеличивали (однако вы даже этого не делаете, потому как `inc eax` закоментарен) то eax стал бы равен 1 примерно после 4млрд минус 0x60883 выполнений цикла, на что потребовался бы стек размером около 16 гигабайт.

Comment: Компилятор начал ругаться на обращение  cmp [edi+ebb-1] , 1 . По этому я представил [edi+ebb-1] через eax . А до этого eax использовался для подсчета количества сдвигов, надо было просто удалить этот комментарий, чтобы не путать.

Comment: @МишаШостак В любом случае если вы думаете что в цикле меняется eax, то покажите явно команду которая была бы внутри вашего цикла и которая бы меняла eax. Замечу, что в ассемблере никакие регистры сами по себе не изменяются, до тех пор пока вы явно не примените команду, которая бы их изменила

Comment: Я в ассемблер работаю очень редко и по надобности, больше c/c++ . По этому моя логика работы программы не такая, не могу все равно понять до конца, что там происходит.

Comment: Я думал так, занести адрес  [edi+ebb-1] разряда в eax, в начале цикла производить сравнение , eax с 1, типа будет ли в адресе [edi+ebb-1] 1 . Потом делать циклический сдвиг в edi, edi - адрес массива. И так по кругу, пока в адресе [edi+ebb-1] разряда не будет 1.

Comment: Сделал вот так в start : lea esi, [edi+ebx-1] /
                         mov eax, esi /
                         cmp eax, 1

Comment: @МишаШостак Ну знаете, на языке C то же самое, если вы какую либо переменную (EAX) не меняете, то ее значение само не изменяется. Почему вы считаете, что у вас в цикле EAX должно измениться ? вот что вы делали в переводе на C: https://pastebin.com/66gnHY8k

Comment: Я добавил изменения для eax. Комментарий выше.

Comment: @МишаШостак `lea esi, [edi+ebx-1] / mov eax, esi / cmp eax, 1` С помощью lea вы помещаете в esi адрес, а не значение, фактически вы делаете esi=edi+ebx-1, т.е. выполняете арифметические операции с указателем. В eax вы просто пощаете такое же значение, как в esi, т.е. указатель. Вот если бы вы написали `mov esi, [edi+ebx-1]` то тогда бы вы в 32 битную переменную esi поместили бы значение четырех байт из массива, т.е. сделали ли бы `int32_t esi=*( (int32_t *) &array[ebx-1])`

Comment: я пробовал так : mov esi, [edi+ebx-1]. Но компилятор ругается.

Comment: @МишаШостак И вы кстати так за все время и не ответили на вопрос: зачем вы помещаете что то в стек. Как именно ругается компилятор, у меня `mov esi, [edi+ebx-1]` отлично компилируется

Comment: Я убрал команду push, на mov eax, [edi+ebx-1] выскакивает Exception в MVS2015 .

Comment: @МишаШостак Exception это не ошибка компиляции ! И да, вполне возможно, что вы выходите за пределы памяти, потому что edi+ebx-1 изначально содержит адрес последнего байта в вашем массиве (и очень вероятно, что это последний байт сегмента данных), а вы по этому адресу пытаетесь считать не байт, а 4 байта. Думаете я просто так писал такую сложную конструкцию `int32_t esi=*( (int32_t *) &array[ebx-1])` что бы объяснить вам, что вы работаете с данными не того размера ? (все регистры названия которых начинаются на `e` являются 32 битными)

Comment: Правильно ли так? Появляется всё равно exception на mov dl, [edi+ebx-1] ( не знаю как исправить) , в eax - количество сдвигов, как вернуть это значение в cnt. https://pastebin.com/r0ySh2jZ

Comment: @МишаШостак Я проблем в коде не вижу. оно должно нормально работать в случае если параметры пришли правильные. Надо запускать под отладчиком и смотреть что в каком параметре поступило и указывает ли оно туда, куда надо

Comment: Вы не знаете как исправить этот exception на mov dl, [edi+ebx-1]. Самое интересное , что этот exception на mvs2017 не появляется , а на 2015 выскакивает

Comment: @МишаШостак Повторяю, проверьте принимаемые параметры, например напечатайте их. А лучше всего посмотрите все под отладчиком. Кто вам сказал, что первый параметр именно по адресу ebp+8, а второй ebp+12. Кто сказал, что параметры вообще в стеке. В зависимости от компилятора и его настроек передача параметров может идти по разному и тогда у вас по указанным смещениям относительно вершины стека лежит совершенно не то, что вы ожидаете. в итоге первая же команда обращения по неправильному адресу вызывает exception